# Using Excel VBA to use a search box, trigger click event and retrieving results?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

After searching every topic I could find on this subject and running into error after error, I've come here hoping somebody can assist me.

I am trying to utilize this website, https://azredistricting.org/districtlocator/, 
to search addresses, which return a legislative / congressional district.

I have attempted variations of the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = Range("address").Row And _
Target.Column = Range("address").Column Then
   Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

   ie.navigate "https://azredistricting.org/districtlocator/"
   ie.Visible = True

   While ie.Busy
   DoEvents
   Wend

   ie.document.getElementById("txtAddress").Value = Range("address")

   While ie.Busy
   DoEvents
   Wend


   Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.document
    Dim sDD As String
    sDD = Trim(Doc.GetElementsByID("districts").innerText)
    MsgBox sDD

End If
```

I keep running into run time errors 424 and another 400 level dealing with strings.

The HTML code I've identified and am attempting to use is

```
<input name="txtAddress" type="text" id="txtAddress" style="color:#214670;background-color:#FFFF99;border-color:#FF3300;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-weight:bold;width:360px;margin-bottom: 0px">
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="Find" onclick="codeAddress()" class="gsc-search-button" title="Enter your address and click here to find your districts">
```

and retrieving the string from

```
<big>29</big>
```

Anyway, I'm completely lost and am about ready to throw in the towel and just manually 10-key this list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just request the data from the Secretary of State? In my state, they comply with these (public) data requests all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Internet Explorer:**

You need to add some waits conditions to allow time for page to properly load and for response text to be present

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, t As Date, address As Object, result As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://azredistricting.org/districtlocator/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set address = .document.querySelector("#txtAddress")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While address Is Nothing

        If Not address Is Nothing Then
            .document.querySelector("#txtAddress").Value = "1100 W. Washington St Phoenix, Arizona 85007"
            .document.querySelector("[value=Find]").Click

            Do
                Set result = .document.querySelector("#districts")
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While result.innerText = vbNullString

            Debug.Print result.innerText
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**XMLHTTP**

I will tidy this up but worth noting if you use the lat and long for the addresses (for example I retrieve these with a call to [opencagedata API](https://opencagedata.com/api), and concantenate these into an xhr post request you can get a json response from both with you can parse with a jsonparser such as [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After adding the .bas to your project you need to go VBE > Tools > References and add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Dim apiKey As String, address As String, url As String, json As Object
    apiKey = "yourAPIkey"
    address = "13 E Tanglewood Trl, Phoenix, AZ 85085" '1100 W. Washington St Phoenix, Arizona 85007
    url = Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(address)
    url = "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=" & address & "&key=" & apiKey & "&pretty=1"

    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)

    Dim dict As Object, lat As String, lng As String
    Set dict = json("results")(1)("geometry")
    lat = dict("lat")
    lng = dict("lng")
       .Open "POST", "https://azredistricting.org/districtlocator/SpatialFunctions.asmx/GetBothDistricts", False
       .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
       .send "{""dblLat"":" & lat & ",""dblLon"":" & lng & ",""locType"":""ROOFTOP""}"

        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        Debug.Print Split(Replace$(Replace$(json("d"), "<b><big><big>", vbNullString), "</big></big></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", Chr$(32)), "<")(0)
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I added some looping and its churning through a list of 3000 as we speak :)